# Salesforce lightning card header background

Tags: datatable, salesforce, lwc, card, lightning

I am trying to change the header color of the card and also there is line after the data table how to get rid of that line. Is it the border of data table.

[image]

I want to get this result

[image]

Is it the lightning card or some other component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust the styles of base Salesforce components, the easiest way is to use the style guide in the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/?variant=wrapper#site-main-content). Here you can get the basic source code to most components and modify them to your liking. For example, this would be the source code to the `lightning-card` component:

```
<article class="slds-card">
  <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
    <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
      <div class="slds-media__figure">
        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="account">
          <lightning-icon icon-name="account"></lightning-icon>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-media__body">
        <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
          <a href="#" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Accounts">
            <span>Accounts</span>
          </a>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">Card Body with Padding</div>
</article>
```